# SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I followed the [guidelines](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/). However I am not able that my project is scanned and keep getting the following error. If I read the "possible causes" I would say I fulfill all of them:

> The SonarQube MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable to collect the required information about your projects.
>
> Possible causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
> 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0 and 15.0 are supported
> 3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
> 4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)

I have a solution file which looks like this:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 15.0.26124.0
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "test", "test.csproj", "{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Debug|x64 = Debug|x64
        Debug|x86 = Debug|x86
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Release|x64 = Release|x64
        Release|x86 = Release|x86
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-yyyyyyyyyy}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

The `.csproj`:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>test</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Rebuild">
    <Message Text="Rebuild selected" Importance="high"/> 
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <Message Text="Clean selected" Importance="high"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

My call looks as follows

```
"d:\jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarScanner_for_MSBuild_4.6\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" begin /k:myKey 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Rebuild
"d:\jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.sonar.MsBuildSQRunnerInstallation\SonarScanner_for_MSBuild_4.6\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe" end
```

and I can see that the project was build

```
13:58:50    Rebuild selected
13:58:50  Done Building Project "d:\jenkins\workspace\test_master\test.csproj" (Rebuild target(s)).
13:58:50  Done Building Project "d:\jenkins\workspace\test_master\test.sln" (Rebuild target(s)).
```

I am using

- SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.6.2
- Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.23107.0

Running the scanner in debug note logs the following

```
Product projects
---------------------------------------


Test projects
---------------------------------------


Invalid projects
---------------------------------------
{none}


Skipped projects
---------------------------------------
{none}


Excluded projects
---------------------------------------
{none}
```

Comment: I already checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49154763/the-sonarqube-msbuild-integration-failed-sonarqube-7-with-scanner-4-0-2-892-an?rq=1 which does not help either

Comment: The build engine 14.0 indicates you use msbuild 14.0 for VS2015. But the solution ile you shared above indicates it's from VS version 15.0(VS2017), which means it needs msbuild 15.0 for VS2017. What's the result if you use msbuild 15.0 if you've installed the VS2017 or build tools for VS2017? (path:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\xxx\MSBuild\15.0\Bin)

Comment: Is that the full content of the project you are trying to analyse? If so, then it doesn't reference any C# files so there is nothing to analyse, and it doesn't reference the standard Microsoft targets so the Sonar-specific builds hooks won't be picked up either so the Scanner can't collect information about the build. Did you mean to reference a project SDK? (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-use-project-sdk?view=vs-2019). Finally, the project is called "test" so even if it were being analyzed it would be treated as a test project.

Comment: Did you check that the scanner can call the SonarQube instance without errors?

Comment: Thanks guys, apparently the project setup (solution, project) was incorrect. I've recreated the solution with VS 2017 and now the scanning was fine.